# Search replace regular expression variable using sed

Tags: sed

This is probably a trivial one:

I have a file (`my.file`) with these lines:

```
>h1_c1
>h1_c2
>h1_c3
>h2_c1
>h2_c2
>h2_c3
```

and I want to change it `in place` to be:

```
>c1_h1
>c2_h1
>c3_h1
>c1_h2
>c2_h2
>c3_h3
```

I thought this ought to do it:

```
sed -i 's/\(\>\)\(h1\)\(\_\)\(.*\)/\1 \4 \3 \2/g' my.file
sed -i 's/\(\>\)\(h2\)\(\_\)\(.*\)/\1 \4 \3 \2/g' my.file
```

but it doesn't seem to work. How do I do it?

Comment: pls confirm that the last line of your output should be `c3_h2` not `h3`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious `sed` for your example is:

```
$ sed -i~ -e 's/^>\(h[0-9]\)_\(c[0-9]\)/>\2_\1/' *.foo
```

I tested this and it works for your example file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `awk`

```
awk -F">|_" '{print ">"$3"_"$2}' my.file > tmp && mv tmp my.file
```

```
awk -F">|_" '{print ">"$3"_"$2}' my.file
>c1_h1
>c2_h1
>c3_h1
>c1_h2
>c2_h2
>c3_h2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `sed`,

```
sed 's/>\(h[1-2]\)_\(.*\)/>\2_\1/' yourfile
```

(OR)

```
sed -r 's/>(h[1-2])_(.*)/>\2_\1/' yourfile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
kent$  sed -r 's/>([^_]*)_(.*)/>\2_\1/' f
>c1_h1
>c2_h1
>c3_h1
>c1_h2
>c2_h2
>c3_h2
```

you add `-i` if you want it to happen "in-place"